# What is the Banach space for multivariate sequences analogous to the $\ell_p$-spaces for univariate sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I am currently self-studying introductory functional analysis and have come across a question none of my textbooks seem to answer.
My question is this: What is the Banach space for multivariate sequences analogous to the $\ell_p$-spaces for univariate sequences?

The resources I have at hand (e.g., Kreyszig: "Introductory Functional Analysis" and Luenberger: "Optimization by Vector Space Methods") only refer to $\ell_p$-spaces for sequences either over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. As the latter references suggests, I am mainly interested in functional analysis from a perspective of dynamic optimization.

One possibility I have come up with from my limited understanding of the topic is to define for the set of sequences $x:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ the "nested" norm
\begin{equation}
||x||=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty ||x_k||_2^p \right)^{1/p}
\end{equation}
where $||x_k||_2$ is the Euclidean norm for the $k$-th component of the sequence $x=(x_k)$. This satisfies the properties of a norm on the sequences space because it "inherits" all the norm properties from the two nested norms. Furthermore, because this nested norm essentially "reduces" the space of multivariate sequences to the single-variable space $\ell_p$, I guess that it should also be complete in the norm etc. However, my skills in this field are not sufficient to verify these guesses.

So what is the "conventional" norm on such a multivariate sequence space, such that this space is complete? And more specifically: what is the *useful* norm for dynamic purposes?

**EDIT:** If my guess is correct, a reference would be helpful, where this is rigorously developed! So far my search has not been fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote down is indeed the canonical choice for the norm. The concept you are looking for (albeit a bit overkill in your setting) is [Bochner spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space) (for the Banach space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and on the measure space $\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure).

The Wikipedia article gives a nice overview and a nice application as well as a further reference.

As a reference, "Vector Measures" by Diestel and Uhl comes to mind, but it is a bit overkill if you are mostly interested in the $\ell_p$-case.